# How to merge interfaces from NPM modules correctly in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The `@types/yandex-maps` package contains `namespace ymaps`.

It has interface `IEventManager`.

I want to add a new method to this interface `IEventManager`.

I'm trying to do this in my file `.d.ts`:

```
import {IEvent} from '@types/yandex-maps';

declare module '@types/yandex-maps' {
    declare namespace ymaps {
        interface IEventManager {
            once(types: string[][] | string[] | string, callback: (event: object | IEvent) => void, context?: object, priority?: number): this;
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work! How do I add the method I need correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Put this `d.ts` file in `types` folder & add it to `include`.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "include": ["types/*.d.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {IEvent} from '@types/yandex-maps';

declare module '@types/yandex-maps' {
    declare namespace ymaps {
        interface IEventManager {
            once(types: string[][] | string[] | string, callback: (event: object | IEvent) => void, context?: object, priority?: number): this;
        }
    }
    export = ymaps;
    export as namespace ymaps;
}
```